# Symfony Unknown raw tag

Tags: symfony

I encountered the following error when I tried to generate a new bundle with Symfony:

> Unknown "raw" tag

[image]

Symfony details:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "gregwar/image-bundle": "^2.1",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3,>=2.3.10",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0",
    "whiteoctober/breadcrumbs-bundle": "*",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a nested `AdministrationBundle`; i.e: `Administration\AdministrationBundle\AdministrationBundle`?

Comment: My steps when i generate Bundle :
1) Enter namespace :  Administrator/AdministratorBundle
2) Bundle Name : AdministratorBundle 
3) Use yml
4) Generate structure : YES
5) Confirm
And here crash.
Thx

Comment: In step 1 above you said you entered the following namespace: "Administrator/AdministratorBundle". However, your screenshot suggests you entered "Administrator/AdministratorBundle/AdministratorBundle". Check your input - it could be the source of your error

Comment: looks similar to this https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/issues/417

Comment: Yeah it looks like 3.0 version of `sensio/generator-bundle` will solve this

Comment: It's one of your Twig files that has `raw` in it. Can you show the respective file and what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

In the new version of Twig tag `raw` had been removed. You should use `verbatim` tag instead. Proof - https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/1.x/lib/Twig/Lexer.php#L302.

So, just search for `{% raw %}` tag in your twig files and replace it with `{% verbatim %}`. 
Then search for `{% endraw %}` and replace it with `{% endverbatim %}`.

Comment: You can also refer to the documentation here.

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/tags/verbatim.html

It says, `New in version 1.12: The verbatim tag was added in Twig 1.12 (it was named raw before).`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `sensio/generator-bundle`: Just remove it from composer.json and run `composer require sensio/generator-bundle` to get the correct version.

Why? This bundle uses the `{% raw %}` tag.